# Difference in throughput between jmeter and apache wrk for same application

Tags: jmeter, wrk

I am hitting two straightforward application URLs from jmeter using 100 threads via HTTP requests and using response assertion (200 OK). No cookie handler or nothing else at all used in jmeter. 
Then using the same machines, I use apache wrk tool (developer asked so) with parameters set to -c100 and -t100. I get throughput difference. The throughput of my application is almost 60 to 80% shown higher via apache wrk compared to jmeter. How do I troubleshoot the difference? Developer is sticking to wrk but I want to resolve the difference. I can provide more info if required but I am not using anything special in jmeter as such.

Comment: If the tested application runs in the same machine as your test client, the answer is pretty simply that JMeter needs more resource. Use a different machine to run the test client.

Comment: I am using separate machine for jmeter. What I meant was that application under test is on same machine for jmeter and wrk - just incase someone was pondering about that point.

Comment: Do you use script languages in JMeter test plan?

Comment: No scripting used for jmeter.

Comment: So, one more question on that front. If jmeter threads are 100 then what does that translate to in wrk context - c100 -t100 , is that correct?

Comment: I know only JMeter. As I have seen on wrks page at github you are correct. You have to take into consideration that in case of JMeter you have a ramp-up period of the test. See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html. It can be that you have a ramp-up in jmeter and you start with full load in wrk.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience wrk is faster, it can deliver as much as up to million requests from single node, quite beefy one though (32 cores with 2 network cards), and it's not apache BTW (while jmeter is). -t100 is probably overkill since your test machine probably has not that much cores. And regarding both throughput and latencies there is [wrk2](http://github.com/giltene/wrk2) tool which gives more correct results for general purpose web services (where the load is not [coordinated](http://github.com/giltene/wrk2))